# How do I pass props to non-child component with react router?

Tags: reactjs, global, react-router

I have a component which *cannot* traditionally inherit `props` from a parent component. This component is rendered via a route and **not** by a parent, I am talking about the `<Single />` component which is the 'detail' component in this setup:

```
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={ProfileList} />
      <Route path="/profile/:username" component={Single} /></Route>
  </Router>
```

Props are available in the `ProfileList` component and that component renders a `Profile` component like so:

```
   /* ProfileList render method */
   render() {
      return (
        <div>
          {this.state.profiles.map((profile, i) => 
            <Profile {...this.state} key={i} index={i} data={profile} />)}
        </div>
      );
    }
```

I am trying to reuse the `Profile` component in both the `ProfileList` and `Single` component:

```
  <Link className="button" to={`/profile/${username}`}>
   {name.first} {name.last}
  </Link>
```

But in the `Single` component I have no way of accessing `state` or `props` - so I have no way of rendering this details view. I know I can either [use `redux` for passing global state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37539781/how-to-pass-props-from-one-component-to-other-in-react-router-that-dont-have-pa) or use query parameters in my `Link to=""`

But I don't want tor reach out for redux yet and don't feel right about query params. So how do I access something like `this.props.profiles` in my `Single` component?

Comment: Maybe Router params? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32901538/how-does-react-router-pass-params-to-other-components-via-props

Comment: no @Brad - I don't want to query params if that is what you mean

Comment: ProfileList and Single are sibling components, then why cannot Single access state?

Comment: Because they are siblings not parent child. The props are in ProfileList - how do I pass them to the Single component that is NOT rendered by ProfileList?

Answer (score 0):

the redux connect() can completely do the job. I think you should use it, because "in fine" you will reimplement a redux connect like